# Why literal value has no type?

Tags: xcode, swift, variables, types, literals

*Type Inference* is a powerful attribute of Swift. It means the compiler can infer the literal's type from its value provided by the programmer, the explicit type specification is not needed.

For example `var IntNum = 3`; the compiler can infer that the variable `IntNum` is of type Int. In Xcode, If user hits the  key and clicks on the variable name, here `IntNum`, then Xcode tells you what the type it is.
However, if I did that on the literal value `3`, Xcode provides nothing. I guess, the literal value I put on the screen simply has no type at all, only the object variable and constant has the type property.

I just guess so, can someone explain that to me?

Cheers
SL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's right.

From [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID322)

> ## Type Safety and Type Inference
>
> Type inference is particularly useful when you declare a constant or
> variable with an initial value. This is often done by assigning a
> literal value (or literal) to the constant or variable at the point
> that you declare it. (A literal value is a value that appears directly
> in your source code)
>
> ...
>
> If you combine integer and floating-point literals in an expression, a
> type of Double will be inferred from the context:
>
> ```
> let anotherPi = 3 + 0.14159
> // anotherPi is also inferred to be of type Double
> ```
>
> **The literal value of 3 has no explicit type in and of itself**, and so
> an appropriate output type of Double is inferred from the presence of
> a floating-point literal as part of the addition.